# Batch file to open one folder with a partial folder name

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch to open directly a folder because the address is too big.

For example I have this folder stuct:

> ```
> Z:\Folder_1\1234_name1\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5
> Z:\Folder_1\3456_name2\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5
> Z:\Folder_1\7891_name3\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5
> Z:\Folder_1\1596_name4\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5
> ...
> ```

So I need a batch that I can enter the number, for example `7891` and it opens the folder that match that number `Z:\Folder_1\7891_name3\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5`.

The problem is that I just know the number but never the name in front of it. The rest, `Folder_1`, `Folder_2`, `Folder_3`, `Folder_4` and `Folder_5` is always the same name.

I was trying something like:

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
:CALLNUMBER

echo Number?
set/p "Number=>"


%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "Z:\Folder_1\%Number%*\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5"
```

This is not working because it does not accept `%Number%*` so it opens my documents folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wild-cards (`?`, `*`) only in the very last element of a path; use [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) as a work-around:

```bat
@echo off
echo Number?
set /P Number=">"

for /D %%D in ("Z:\Folder_1\%Number%_*") do (
    "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" "%%~D\Folder_2\Folder_3\Folder_4\Folder_5"
)
```